# How do I create a custom keybind to go back a page in Chrome on MacOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

I have a mouse with lots of buttons and would like to bind one button to "Back a page" in Chrome.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Whoever vtc'd this as a PSL request needs to read the question more carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, I figured it out! You need to go to

- System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Shortcuts -> App Shortcuts
- Click the `+`
- Select `All Applications`
- Menu Title should be `Back`

Press the key you wish to bind

Comment: This seems an about-face way to do it. Why not bind the mouse button to  ⌘[ in the mouse's control panel? That way it would be consistent with any app/browser, as that's the default key command for 'Back'.